# hibernate validator dynamic parameters with internationalization

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am using hibernate validator framework like below

```
@NotBlank(message = ValidationConstants.FileErrCodes.ERINF042)  
@Size(max = ValidationConstants.FieldSizes.ACCOUNT_TYPE, message = ValidationConstants.FileErrCodes.ERINF043)  
@Pattern(regexp = ValidationConstants.Pattern.PATTERN_NUMERIC, message = ValidationConstants.FileErrCodes.ERINF044)  
private String accountType;
```

i have properties file like below for english

```
accountType.ERINF042 = Account type can not be blank.
accountType.ERINF043 = Account type can not exceed 2 characters.
accountType.ERINF044 = Account type must be in numeric.
```

for french

```
accountType.ERINF042 = Le type de compte ne peut pas être vide.
accountType.ERINF043 = Le type de compte ne peut pas dépasser 2 caractères
accountType.ERINF044 = Le type de compte doit être numérique.
```

like this i have account number, account sub type.... fields
for all fields do i need to write all messages..?
or is there any other way to dynamically add fields like

```
accountType.ERINF042 = {0} can not be blank.
accountType.ERINF043 = {0} can not exceed {1) characters.
accountType.ERINF044 = {0} must be in numeric.
```

if yes how to send french and english parameters...

help me..

Comment: I decided to use messages like `Value can not be blank`/`Value must be in numeric`. In this case, the messages a unified and because they're shown near the fields, user still can understand which exactly value has failed.

Comment: Also instead of overriding original translation in every place (`@NotNull(message = "my message"`), I'm overriding it once and for all such validators (`javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message = Value must not be empty`).

Comment: But i cant put a unified message... it is requirement.

Comment: Another way is to use `payload` field (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints-constraintannotation, see example about severity) together with EL for getting its value (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-message-interpolation). But you unfortunately it won't work for you, because you also need to translate a field name.

Comment: I don't see easy ways to do it, so the only way that will work is to write your own validators and don't use standards. In this case, you can add any attributes to the annotation and later use them in the message. Or even set a proper message from the validator implementation.

Comment: my own validator..? can you help me with that... can i achieve internationalization also with that..?

Comment: Links to the documentation above contain all information that you need. I hope that it will help you :)